# why Google Search Api not getting indexed page result?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, google-api

Developed a Wordpress Plugin to Index Pages in Google.The Pages getting indexed,i checked it by site:url in google search,it showing result.but not getting result while check through my code.
here is my code

```
$ip_server=$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
$site_url=site_url();
$query =urlencode('http://helpfultherapy.com/best-therapy-for-you/');
$url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&"
    . "q=site:$query&userip=$ip_server";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $site_url);
    $body = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $json = json_decode($body);


$json->responseData->  // results is getting null here
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is success for me, make sure **curl** extension is enabled on your server,

Properly escape the below line of code:

```
$url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site:".$query."&userip=".$ip_server;
```

try with replacing the $url in your code....

Comment: i got responseData with an stdClass Object array in it.

Comment: i can also get response data,but $json->responseData->results returns an empty array

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly from my end after adding this option for `https` handling.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```